# Can I wipe a password reset disk?

Tags: windows, wipe

Say I made a password reset disk. However, I found it best not to exist, I remember my password quite well. Now, how do I make sure that Windows doesn't prompt "Reset password", make the disk blank, but keep it usable?
(Complete computer noob.)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the disk for other purposes? What kind of disk is it?

Comment: Its a flash drive. I want to remove it's password reset capability but still be able to use it. (not destroy the flash)

Comment: Just format it like any other drive?  Of course be warned,if for any reason your password does not work to mount your encrypted volume, you are getting rid of the **only** thing that can help you access your data.

Comment: Ok, my question now is: Can i stop windows prompting "Reset password" if I made a password reset disk?

Answer (score -1):

Just wipe it with nwipe, dban or whatever you like.

http://www.dban.org/download

Comment: But will it prevent windows from prompting "Reset password"? I don't like seeing it every time i make a typo.